# Automatic Node ID assignment for LSS Slaves without LSS Master

Tags: can-bus, canopen

I am currently doing a system design with CANopen communication and I am curious about the following question.

In the system a device is programmed to have no Node-Id assigned (255) on startup. Normaly a LSS Master now has to assign a specific Node-Id to the device to work properly. However, if there is no LSS Master functionality implemented in any other bus node, does the CANopen standard allows the the unconfigured device to assign itself a predefined ID after a timeout?

In my opinion this is not possible because it can lead to undefined system states but I could not find anything in the standard documents.

Comment: From what I remember, compliant CANopen systems are explicitly forbidden to change node id on the fly, or through SDO/PDO access. Some external means (like a dip switch) or LSS are required.

Comment: Btw valid node id are 1 to 127 so I don't know where you got 255 from. Default node id is normally 1.

Comment: As far as I remember it, unconcfigured Nodes all have ID 255 assigned because they can't have no Node Id.